# the procedure entry point sprintf_s could not be located in DLL

Tags: windows-xp

We are using windows XP SP3 version "PosReady" which is still supported by MS.

We have several old computers running on this OS.

Recently we have problem with any software using msvcrt.dll.

Constantly this message popup shows:
"the procedure entry point sprintf_s could not be located in DLL msvcrt.dll".
Tried removing and reinstalling all MS visual C++ run times but it did not help.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uninstall the Windows XP updates that were pushed out February 12.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer to explain why this will fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There was an express update pushed through Windows Update yesterday (FEB-16), that **solves the issue** and is listed in my installed updates as:

**Security Update for Windows XP (KB4487085-v2)**

So it seems the issue was in the first version of that update.
Microsoft in [4487085](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4487085/security-update-for-vulnerabilities-in-windows-xp-embedded) states:

*This update was rereleased February 15, 2019 to address a known issue that occurred when you installed the original February 12, 2019 version of the update.*

and

*After you install the originally released version of this security update (from February 12, 2019), applications that use the msvcrt.dll dynamic link library (DLL) do not load properly.*

Answer (score -1):

Windows update, via the "shield" in task bar, notified me that there were updates. I installed them and after reboot had the issue described here. So, pretty obvious what the problem was. I used "Add/Remove Programs" to uninstall the nine or so updates that were showing for that date.

Most of the updates affected .NET libraries and I think that's where the problem is. The newest MSVCRT.DLL on my system is from 2012, even when the updates were still installed, so messing with them won't help.

Ideally, MS will fix this, but if not, we're almost out of support anyway. Don't forget to disable automatic updates or the problem will come back.